# Export firestore data by overwriting existing data gcloud firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

I am trying to overwrite existing export data in gcloud using:

`gcloud firestore export gs://<PROJECT>/dir --collection-ids='tokens'`

But I get this error:

`(gcloud.firestore.export) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Path already exists: /fcm-test-firebase.appspot.com/dir/dir.overall_export_metadata`

Is there anyway to either delete the path or export with replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily determine the list of available flags for any `gcloud`.

Here are variants of the command and you can see that there's no overwrite option:

- [`gcloud firestore export`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/export)
- [`gcloud alpha firestore export`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/firestore/export)
- [`gcloud beta firestore export`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/firestore/export)

Because the export is too a Google Cloud Storage  (GCS) bucket, you can simply delete the path before attempting the export.

**BE VERY CAREFUL** with this command as it recursively deletes objects

```bash
gsutil rm -r gs://<PROJECT>/dir
```

If you would like Google to consider adding an overwrite feature, consider filing a feature request on it's public [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

I **suspect** that the command doesn't exist for various reasons:

1. GCS storage is **cheap**
2. Many backup copies is ∞>> no backup copies
3. It's easy to delete copies using `gsutil`