# Error : INVALID_ARGUMENT: Path already exists when scheduled firestore export job runs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, google-cloud-scheduler

I followed the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export) for scheduling firestore export via cloud function and cloud scheduler.

It works perfectly only for the first time creating the necessary exports at the right location.

When I run it again I get following error in cloud function.
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Path already exists: /red115.appspot.com/daily_backup/users.overall_export_metadata

Why doesn't it overwrite on existing data?

I followed official docs, gave the necessary roles & permissions to principal account.
[image]

Comment: Updated the answer as per given error.

Comment: can you take a look at my answer, again ?

Answer (score 0):

I have Recreated the setup from the docs you shared. I am assuming you also did the [Configure access permissions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#configure_access_permissions) part. I have scheduled the firebase function for firestore export every 5 minutes on all collections. And even after running 4 times with the schedule I have not got the Error you have mentioned.

The Firebase Storage Rules you provided do not affect the Firestore export functionality, they are only for the Firebase Storage.

But if you are experiencing this error I will recommend you to first check whether the export is already created at the given specified location on that bucket.

- If `Yes` then To overwrite existing data on Firestore export, you could add a step in your Cloud Function to delete the existing export if there exists before running the new export. Something like this : `admin.storage().bucket().delete()` (be specific about this thing) method to delete the existing export before running the new export.
  **OR**
  You could change the export path to include a timestamp or a version number, so that each export is saved to a unique location. Which is a default behavior.
- If `No` then there must be a typo that happened in the following line while providing the bucket link `const bucket = 'gs://BUCKET_NAME';`

Make sure you provide the same `gs://BUCKET_NAME` in the `functions/index.js` and `gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:admin \ gs://BUCKET_NAME`

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72292068/20239914) also talks about the wrong gsutil path you have a look at once as well..

Comment: I've given permission using IAM Console. Please check screenshot attached in original question.

I tried exporting all_collections, it works first time successfully by exporting all collections.
I tried giving permission using cloud shell, I get error.

gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:red115@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:admin \
    gs://red115.appspot.com/export_data/all_collections
Omitting prefix "gs://red115.appspot.com/export_data/all_collections/". (Did you mean to do iam -r?)
CommandException: No URLs matched. Do the files you're operating on exist?

Comment: @TimmySimons It seems like you're trying to set the admin role on a folder that does not exist yet, Please check whether `export_data/all_collections` actually a folder exist on that given bucket if not then you need to create the folder first, then run the iam command again.